# Почему возникает ошибка "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Tags: python, функции, python-faq

```
def hello(name, eyes, old):
    print('Привет, '+ name + '!')
    print('Привет, ' , name , '!')
    print('Твой цвет глаз: ' + eyes)
    print('Твой возраст: '+ old)
hello ("Даниил", "карие", "27")
```

Ошибка:

```
File "/tmp/sessions/76bc0639bb20652b/main.py", line 4  
print('Привет, ', name, '!')
........................................^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

По советам, еще раз перенабил отступы табами, все заработало. Всем спасибо!
Подскажите, как комментарий отметить решением вопроса?

Comment: хммм, если скопировать ваш пример и вставить в репл, то все ок https://repl.it/repls/GuiltyHastyLines

Comment: @AlexanderChernin запятые тут не причем, можно через запятые несколько объектов передать

Comment: скорее всего опечатка, табы вместо пробелов или что-то в этом роде

Comment: Где-то вместо пробелов символ табуляции, его нужно заменить на пробелы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы скопировать "оригинальные" пробельные символы из вопроса, надо нажать *править* и выделить и скопировать текст из текстового поля.

Я вставил этот текст в Notepad++:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из этого следует, что вы где-то вводили символ табуляции, а где-то обычные пробелы. Чтобы код работал, отступы в методе должны быть одинаковыми. В вашем случае либо 4 пробела, либо символ табуляции.

**[Дополнительная информация об отступах в коде Python (PEP 8)](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id4)**

> **Табуляция или пробелы?**
>
> Пробелы - самый предпочтительный метод отступов.
>        Табуляция должна использоваться только для поддержки кода, написанного с отступами с помощью табуляции.
>        Python 3 запрещает смешивание табуляции и пробелов в отступах.
>        Python 2 пытается преобразовать табуляцию в пробелы.
>        Когда вы вызываете интерпретатор Python 2 в командной строке с параметром -t, он выдает предупреждения (warnings) при использовании
>   смешанного стиля в отступах, а запустив интерпретатор с параметром
>   -tt, вы получите в этих местах ошибки (errors). Эти параметры очень рекомендуются!

Comment: а разве табы можно? Мне казалось питон жестко ограничивает 4мя пробелами отступы

Comment: @Grundy не ограничивает

Comment: @Grundy, можно табы, можно пробелы (любое количество - хоть 1, хоть 10) - главное чтобы unindent "матчил" какой-то внешний indentation level. Но по pep8 рекомендуется 4 пробела.