# unindent does not match any outer indentation level, перевел, не врубаюсь

Tags: python

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", 0)
Config.set("graphics", "width", 500)
Config.set("graphics", "hight", 500)


class CalculatorApp(App):

    def build(self):
        boxlay = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.lbl = Label(text="", font_size=20, halign="right", valign="center", size_hint=(1, .4))
        gridlay = GridLayout(cols=4, size_hint=(1, .6))
        self.floatlay_grid = FloatLayout()
        boxlay.add_widget(self.lbl)



        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="7"))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="8"))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="9"))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="x"))

        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="4"))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="5"))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="6"))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="/"))

        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="1"))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="2"))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="3"))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text="+"))

        gridlay.add_widget(self.floatlay_grid)
        self.floatlay_grid.add_widget(Button(text = "0", size = (200, 50)))
        self.floatlay_grid.add_widget(Button(text = ",", pos = (200, 0)))




        boxlay.add_widget(gridlay)
        return boxlay


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CalculatorApp().run()
```

Comment: Я так полагаю, вы ловите ошибку на этапе выполнения. Не могли бы вы привести хотя бы полный текст ошибки? Не говоря уже о том, чтобы подробно описать проблему. :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подскажите, почему при запуске ругается на "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981644/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-indentationerror-unindent-does-not)

Comment: Что вы воздух пинаете? Ваш код прекрасно работает!