# Python. Как удалить несколько похожих файлов в папке?

Tags: python, файлы, удаление

Допустим у меня в корневой папке есть папка с названием photo, внутри неё находятся фотографии с названием "User_1_1.jpg","User_1_2.jpg","User_2_1.jpg","User_2_2.jpg" и т.д. Как мне удалить все файлы с названием, например, начинающимся на "User_1_"? То есть программа должна удалить все файлы, которые начинаются на "User_1_". Вместо 1 может быть любое значение, которое я введу.

Пробовал примерно вот так и другими способами, только получается ошибка доступа вроде

---

```
a5 = ln6.get()
#files = glob.glob('photo')
files = glob.glob('/photo/User_' + a5 + '_' + '*.jpg')#тут ошибка
for f in files:
    try:
        f.unlink()
        #f.unlink('/User_' + a5 + '_' + '*.jpg')
    except OSError as e:
        print("Ошибка: %s : %s" % (f, e.strerror))
```

Дополнение: программа не может найти папку
Попробовал вот так, но не получилось все равно

```
a5 = ln6.get()
mask = 'User_'+a5+'_'
folder = pathlib.Path().absolute()
direct = os.listdir(fr'{folder}/photo')
print(folder)
for file in direct:
    if mask in file:
        path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), file)
        os.remove(path)
```

Такая ошибка:

> os.remove(path)
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'C:\Users\Vlad\NewDip\User_10_1.jpg'

или(с двумя \, но не показывается тут)

> os.remove(path1) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти
> указанный файл: 'C:\Users\Vlad\NewDip\User_10_1.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

mask = 'user_1_'
direct = os.listdir('/photo')
for file in direct:
    if mask in file:
        path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), file)
        os.remove(path)
```

Comment: Ошибка в конце строки direct = os.listdir('/photo')

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: проблему с отступами реши допустим как вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981644/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-indentationerror-unindent-does-not

Comment: Да, это я уже увидел, только появилась другая проблема, папку не может найти программа, дополнил вопрос

Comment: cd photo && pwd

Comment: Это в os.listdir('cd photo && pwd')? Если да, то ошибка остается, что не удается найти путь, а если без кавычек, то ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: у меня нет виндовой тачки тебе нужно указать полный путь к директории photo (например вот так C:\Users\Vlad\NewDip\)

Comment: Я собираюсь позже сделать .exe из этого файла, чтобы можно было запустить на другом ПК, как тогда потом она найдет путь к папке photo. Нужно чтобы именно в папке рядом с файлом она нашла папку photo и там уже дальше искала, что удалять. Была уже такая ошибка в другом, но folder = pathlib.Path().absolute() и fr'{folder}/папка' помогли её решить, а сейчас почему-то не работает, тогда мне нужно было создать файл в определенной папке

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]