# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, discord.py

При запуске бота появляется ошибка: **IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level**, код:

```
async def cat(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/img/cat')
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x2f3136, title = '**Мистер Кэт :cat:')
    embed.set_image(url = json_data['link'])
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: В отступах перемешаны табы и пробелы, используйте только что-то одно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981644/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-ind)

Answer (score 0):

Выделите блок кода, где эта ошибка и нажмите `ТАБ`

Answer (score 0):

Тщательно проверьте отступы (Должна быть одна табуляция). Эта ошибка означает что у Вас где-то неправильные отступы. Кстати в сообщении об ошибке указывается где именно она возникает в такой форме:

```
File [Путь к файлу], line [Номер строки] 
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```