# Не запускается код что делать?

Tags: python

Вот код(скажите что в нем не так)

```
import sys 
import time
import random

wh = input("Вы хотите начислить деньги на киви(да или нет)?: ")
if wh == "Да" or wh == "да":
    print("Окей")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Генерируем деньги...")
    rn = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Ваши деньги: " + str(rn) + " рублей!")
    kr = input("Введите номер карты киви: ")
    print("Хорошо! Перевод денег на " + kr + "...")
    time.sleep(6)
    print('Деньги зачислены!')
    yt = input("Взломать ютуб(да или нет)?: ")
elif yt  == "Нет" or yt == "нет":
    print("Ну тогда досвидания!")
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit()
elif yt == "Да" or yt == "да":
    print("Начинаю взлом ютуба")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Ютуб взломан!")
    kp = input("Укажите имя канала: ")
    print("Хорошо! Зачисление подписчиков на канал " + kp)
    time,sleep(5)
    rnn = random.randint(1, 10000000)
    print("Зачислено: " + str(rnn))
    print("Удачи!")
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit()
elif wh == "Нет" or wh == "нет":
    sys.exit() 
else:
    sys.exit()
input()
```

Comment: Что значит не запускается? Какая-то ошибка вылезает или что?

Comment: нет он просто автоматически закрывается

Comment: через файл не запускается

Comment: Запускайте через консоль, возможно какие-то ошибки возникают.

Comment: пишет IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Вообще-то если скопировать отсюда код, то он нормально запускается. Приведите ошибку **полностью** в самом вопросе, все её строки. Там должно быть написано, на какую строку оно ругается и многое станет понятнее

Comment: Возможно, содержимое файла не соответствует тому что вы видете в текстовом редакторе. (Не нажата кнопка save, или вообще редактируете другой файл...) Наберите в консоле `type имя_файла.py`, Чтобы проверить.

Comment: Ошибка, как минимум, здесь: `time,sleep(5)`. Нужна точка, а не запятая. Плюс у вас с условиями что-то непонятное. Вы, похоже, с вложенностью напутали

Comment: Конкретно IndentationError возникает из-за того, что у вас табы и пробелы одновременно используются: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGsna.png

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/981644/1365)

Comment: @CrazyElf, копировать нужно из режима редактирования вопроса, тогда код именно так скопируется, как был вставлен. При рендеринге маркдауна в html табы автоматом в пробелы переводит, поэтому не будет видно, что там табы на самом деле, если просто код скопировать.

Comment: 1. причём в елифе `yt` 2. почему после `sleep`  `,` 3. на кой вы в условии используете `or` если можно `.lower()` 4. f-строки для слабых, да? 5. название переменных 11/10

Comment: 1. я создал переменную yt для продолжения кода 2. Моя ошибка 3.я привык так

Answer (score 0):

Все работает, скорее всего, когда отвечаете на первый вопрос, попадает в строку пробел, что приводит к выходу из приложения.
Можно использовать strip(), убирает пробелы из начала и конца.