# Почему происходит ошибка "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" в моём коде?

Tags: python, python-3.6

**Проблема**: Происходит ошибка.

Вот текст этой ошибки:

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

**Что я пробовал**: В интернете пишут, что из-за отступов, но сколько их не исправлял - и табами, и пробелами делал, ничего не выходит.

**Код**:

```py
import random

SZUBIENICA = ['''
 +---+
     |
     |
     |
   ===''', '''
 +---+
 0   |
     |
     |
   ===''','''
 +---+
 0   |
 |   |
     |
   ===''','''
 +---+
 0   |
/|   |
     |
   ===''','''
 +---+
 0   |
/|\  |
     |
   ===''','''
 +---+
 0   |
/|\  |
/    |
   ===''','''
 +---+
 0   |
/|\  |
/ \   |
   ===''']
slowy = 'аист акула бабуин баран барсук бобр бык верблюд волк воробей ворон выдра голубь гусь жаба зебра змея индюк кит кобра коза козел койот корова кошка кролик крыса курица лама ласка лебедь лев лиса лосось лось лягушка медведь моллюск моль мул муравей мышь норка носорог обезьяна овца окунь олень орел осел панда паук питон попугай пума семга скунс собака сова тигр тритон тюлень утка форель хорек черепаха ястреб ящерица'.split()

pravidlowy = ''
zly = ''

def randSlowo(words):

    i = random.randint(0,len(words)-1)
    randomnoje_slowo = words[i]
    return randomnoje_slowo

def odberLiter(wszystke):

    while True:

        liter = input('Введите букву: ')
        liter.lower()

        if liter != 1:
            print('Введите пожалуйста одну букву.')

        elif liter in wszystke:
            print ('Вы уже вводили эту букву! Введите другую.')

        elif liter not in 'йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэюбьтимсчя':
            print ('Введите пожалуйста БУКВУ')

        else:
            return
slowo = odberLiter(slowy)

liter = odberLiter(pravidlowy + zly)

print(liter)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981644/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-ind)

Comment: я уже пробовал исправить ВЕСЬ код и пробелами, и табами, но ничего не выходит

Comment: у меня при запуске пишет `введите пожалуйста одну букву` видимо что-то с кодировкой еще, посмотрю сейчас

Comment: Все что я вижу что сами условия игры вероятно неправильно написаны, но сама ошибка с пробелами не воспроизводится. Код взял из вопроса вставил и работает. только `liter != 1` не верное условие нужно сравнивать длину а не число с буквой

Comment: В общем ошибка у меня не воспроизводится, логика игры не совсем правильная, но это дело поправимое.

Comment: В показанном вами коде в if-elif-else смешаны табы и пробелы